# RegEx for matching and excluding ' and "

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group, regex-greedy

I know that to negate a character like `'` I can write `[^']`.

Bu I want to capture any character (repeated zero or more times) but this character should not be single or double quote:

```
"[^'""]*"
```

Is this the right syntax?

Comment: What are the outer double quotes? Why two double quotes inside character class? Is it C#?

Comment: I write the regexp in MySQL regexp. If I enclosed the regexp in `" "` then I need to add `""` if used as part of the regexp.

Answer (score 0):

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/FhzdyC/1) might help you to do so:

```
([^"'])*
```

You might also want to use:

```
([^\x22\x27])*
```

Which you can simplify it as an expression maybe [similar to](https://regex101.com/r/wZum1x/1) so that to capture everything else that you wish except <kbd>'</kbd> and <kbd>"</kbd> in a capturing group:

```
([^\x27\x22]*)
```

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work and you can visualize other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Test

```js
const regex = /([^\x27|\x22])*/gm;
const str = `anything else9*F&(A*&Fa09s7f'"'''"afa'"adfadsf`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Both versions of the expressions are "correct".  Pipe vs. no pipe is a "quibble".  Personally, I sometimes *LIKE* seeing a pipe where it's not strictly "required" - it can  often help make the regex more readable.  Nevertheless - Ms. Peel gave a good answer to a valid question.

Comment: @paulsm4 It is not wrong to add the pipe, only if it is in the [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) it will also not be matched. (Btw, the downvote is not mine)

Comment: `([^"'])*` will this exclude `"` and ` '` ?? Or just the `"`?

Comment: I have doubt. I tried [link](https://regex101.com/r/FhzdyC/1) and it matches the whole string. This is my regex: `\b.*([^"'])*.*\b` and this is my string: `ab"cde` while I have a `"` it still matched the whole string?